# Is $x^3 +2x^2 + 2x + 1$ completely reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is $x^3 +2x^2 + 2x + 1$ completely reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

A polynomial is called completely reducible if it can be factorized into linear factors.

$x^3 +2x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x+1)(x^2+x+1)$

I see that when I plug in $2$ in $(x^2+x+1)$, it becomes $7$ which is $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7.$

Is that why the given function is completely reducible?

Then what is $q(x)$ in $(x+1)(x-2)q(x)$? How do you factor out $(x-2)$ from $(x^2+x+1)$?

Comment: You can factor it as $(x-2)(x-4)$ modulo 7

Comment: Solve for $a$ in $(x+a)(x-2)=x^2+x+1$  We must have $-2a\equiv1\mod7$

Comment: Also you can do synthetic division / polynomial long division mod $p$.

Comment: $4+2+1=7$ ....................